# Videogular controls not fully rendering

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I'm implementing a site that is using Videogular to play the videos as it integrates nicely with the rest of the AngularJS within the site. Every file that is needed appears to be in the correct location in the path but the end result is only the total time, the elapsed time, and the elapsed time bar are shown.

Now I now the controls are there as if I hover over where the volume control should be the volume appears.

I'm testing in Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107. I think I followed the demo to the letter.

This is how I"m referencing the specific style sheets

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/offcanvas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/videogular/videogular.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app2.css"/>
```

This is how I'm pulling in the js files. Not shown are inclusion of jquery, bootstrap, and offcanvas js files.

```
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/videogular/videogular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/videogular/plugins/controls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/videogular/plugins/overlay-play.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/videogular/plugins/buffering.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/videogular/plugins/poster.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

I even used the same config as the demo

```
  $scope.config = {
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    autoHide: false,
    autoPlay: true,
    responsive: true,
    theme: {
      url: "css/videogular/videogular.css",
      playIcon: "&#xe000;",
      pauseIcon: "&#xe001;",
      volumeLevel3Icon: "&#xe002;",
      volumeLevel2Icon: "&#xe003;",
      volumeLevel1Icon: "&#xe004;",
      volumeLevel0Icon: "&#xe005;",
      muteIcon: "&#xe006;",
      enterFullScreenIcon: "&#xe007;",
      exitFullScreenIcon: "&#xe008;"
    }
```

Finally my directory structure is this:

- app

  - css
  - videogular

    - fonts

      - icomoon.eot
      - icomoon.svg
      - icomoon.ttf
      - icomoon.woff
    - videogular.css
  - img
  - js

    - videogular
    - plugins

      - buffering.js
      - controls.js
      - overlay-play.js
      - poster.js
    - videogular.js
  - lib
  - partials
  - videos
  - views

    - videogular

      - plugins

        - buffering

          - buffering.html
        - controls

          - controls.html
          - full-screen-button.html
          - mute-button.html
          - play-pause-button.html
          - volume-bar.html
        - overlay-play

          - overlay-play.html
  - index.html

Now I'm certain I'm missing something but I can't see it. Any help?

Comment: Any Chrome error or do you see any network errors? It seems everything fine for me, maybe if you could upload a demo to take a look it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. Based on the comment from elecash to the question that everything looked correct I compared everything to the demo. As it turns out my mistake was getting the icomoon font from the icomoon website and not the demo. Without the unicode definitions defined in the icomoon.svg it had no means of knowing the correct glyphy to display eventhough it was correctly defined in the config correctly. A quick download of the font files and restarting of the server and everything rendered correctly.

Comment: Cool, glad to help! You should always use icon fonts provided because they're optimized to have only the glyph used in the project